# Aligning multiple rows and columns with different number of equations (Align environment)

Tags: equations, align

I am trying to achieve the following structuring with an *align* environment:
Each of the first two rows has 2 equations, which should be aligned. In the third and fourth row, there should be one centered equation in each case.
With my approach those criteria are mainly satisfied, but the horizontal space is way to large and it looks somehow irregular. So I would like to ask how I can get the 3./4. row to be between the two equation in the first two lines.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        x1&=y1  &       a1&=b1 \label{eq:a} \\
        x2&=y2  &       a2&=b2 \label{eq:b} \\
    \begin{split}
        x3=y3 \\
        a3=b3
        \label{eq:c}
    \end{split}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

The following approach would be perfect, if there wasn't a blank line between the two align environments.

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        x1&=y1  &       a1&=b1 \label{eq:a} \\
        x2&=y2  &       a2&=b2 \label{eq:b}
    \end{align}
    \begin{align}
    \begin{split}   
        x3=y3 \\
        a3=b3
        \label{eq:c}
    \end{split} 
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

I really hope you can understand my English :D
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thank you... next time, there won't be any emotions of gratitude or salutation in my question ;)

Comment: I don't mind emotions of gratitude or salutation at all, but some people here do. The welcome message is a standard one we use over here. Just remember to upvote answers that you find useful, and accept the one which helped you most. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat}{3}
        x1&=y1  &  &  &      a1&=b1 \label{eq:a} \\
        x2&=y2  & & &      a2&=b2 \label{eq:b} \\
        && \begin{aligned}
         x3&=y3 \\
         a3&=b3
        \end{aligned}& &
        \label{eq:c}
    \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat}{3}
        x1&=y1  & \qquad\qquad & \qquad\qquad &      a1&=b1 \label{eq:a} \\
        x2&=y2  & & &      a2&=b2 \label{eq:b} \\
        && \mathclap{\begin{aligned}
         x3&=y3 \\
         a3&=b3
        \end{aligned}}& &
        \label{eq:c}
    \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The long third equation version:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat}{3}
        x1&=y1  & \qquad\qquad & \qquad\qquad &      a1&=b1 \label{eq:a} \\
        x2&=y2  & & &      a2&=b2 \label{eq:b} \\
        && \mathclap{\begin{aligned}
         x3&=y3 +a1 -d1 +e5 +a1 -d1 +e5 \\
         a3&=b3
        \end{aligned}}& &
        \label{eq:c}
    \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The centered long third equation version:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat}{3}
        x1&=y1  & \qquad\qquad & \qquad\qquad &      a1&=b1 \label{eq:a} \\
        x2&=y2  & & &      a2&=b2 \label{eq:b} \\
        && \mathclap{\begin{gathered}
         x3=y3 +a1 -d1 +e5 +a1 -d1 +e5 \\
         a3=b3
        \end{gathered}}& &
        \label{eq:c}
    \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer too!! Now I'll try to find out, how this exactly works

Comment: @Jan Sure. In case of doubt, please leave a comment for clarification. BTW run `texdoc amsldoc` from command prompt to open `amsmath` documentation and try to search for `alignat`.

Comment: I tried these approaches. Unfortunately, if the last two equations get longer, the upper two rows will be pushed too far apart. Is there a possibility to center equation (3) like above, without affecting this distance?

Comment: @Jan See the update. You need to use `\mathclap` versions for that.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to remove that spacing with

```
\vspace*{\dimexpr-\abovedisplayshortskip-\belowdisplayskip-\belowdisplayshortskip\relax}
```

The second `align` is better to be replaced by `equation`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        x1&=y1  &       a1&=b1 \label{eq:a} \\
        x2&=y2  &       a2&=b2 \label{eq:b}
    \end{align}
    \vspace*{\dimexpr-\abovedisplayshortskip-\belowdisplayskip-\belowdisplayshortskip\relax}
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        x3=y3 \\
        a3=b3
        \label{eq:c}
    \end{split}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks beautiful, thank you very much. Can you tell me why I should use the equation environment?

Comment: @Jan `align` is needed only when you have to align something, which is not this case. In cases where you haven't to align anything, `equation` is the right choice.

Comment: if this happens to come at the end of a page, i believe the separate `equation` would be quite able to split to a new page, which isn't desirable.